# Travel with my dog from Italy to the Philippines

Tags: air-travel, philippines, pets

Could I travel from Italy to Philippines with my big dog in the cargo compartment? Is there a way I can figure out in advance how much it would cost?

Comment: Are we talking one-way or return? If the latter, for how long of a stay and for what reason? And are you ready to pay big money for it?

Comment: Looks like there will also be significant requirements in terms of permits and veterinary tests: https://www.philippine-embassy.org.sg/the-philippines-2/bringing-pets-to-the-philippines/ http://www.pettravel.com/immigration/Philippines.cfm  If the dog returns to Italy, expect another round of the same.

Comment: I would avoid flights for a big dog. It's a big stress for them and some of them die.

Comment: And there is a way to find out how much the flight would cost, call the airline. They will also tell you what they require (a special crate, certificates etc); add those costs too.